# Rebus Pub / Sub Encryption

Tags: rebus

Is it possible to turn of message encryption on subscription messages?

We want to let external parties subscribe to messages via AzureServiceBus and SAS keys pr queue, but we use Encryption of messages and don't want to expose that key to external parties.

One way is to create another bus to that, but that just seems complicated, is there another way?

Also want to thank you for quick repons here on Stack overflow and a great product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably achieve what you want by wrapping [the outgoing step that encrypts the message body](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Encryption/EncryptMessagesOutgoingStep.cs) in something that would decide to invoke the step (and thus encrypt the body) or not, depending on the message's [intent value in the headers](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Messages/Headers.cs#L77-L80), but I think that is a little bit icky.

The reason I think it is icky, is because I think you should treat your encrypted bus as an internally used bus only, and then have a completely separate bus that you use to publish messages to third parties.

This separation would have the benefit that you can update internal message schemas etc. without worrying about breaking anything in the integration with your external parties.

Comment: You are probably right that it's a good thing to separate these two buses. Booth for security concerns as well as business separation.